# matplotlib - dataframe - How to have real map on the background in matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

The codes below put dots on the specific points on the earth map.

```
num_samples = 1250000
indices = np.random.choice(df.index, num_samples)
df_x = df.df_longitude[indices].values
df_y = df.df_latitude[indices].values

sns.set_style('white')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 12))

ax.scatter(df_x, df_y, s=5, color='red', alpha=0.5)

ax.set_xlim([-74.10, -73.60])  
ax.set_ylim([40.85, 40.90])    

ax.set_title('coordinates')
```

Is there any way to put these dots on a map instead of this white background?

Please have a look at the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[geopandas](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html) provides an API that makes this quite easy. Here is an example, where the map is zoom into the continent of Africa:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import geopandas

df = pd.DataFrame(
   {'Latitude': np.random.uniform(-20,10, 100),
    'Longitude': np.random.uniform(40,20, 100)})

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

ax = world[world.continent == 'Africa'].plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')

# We can now plot our ``GeoDataFrame``.
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')

plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]